# How to install a service on windows 7 without Visual Studio?

Tags: windows-7, windows-services

Install a windows service: there is a util with Visual Studio: InstallUtil.exe.
If I have a service MyService.exe and want to install it on a windows 7 without Visual Studio on it, how can I install it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try NSSM (Non-Sucking Service Manager) for the times the "sc" doesn't work quite as expected.  http://nssm.cc

I had an service I built in Go not too long ago that I could not get to run under "sc", nssm worked perfectly.

Answer (score 13):

One way is to use sc.exe, which is part of OS. Example:

```
sc create **ServiceName** start= auto binPath= "c:\mydir\myService.exe"
```

where binPath is exe file containing your service.

if you don't want start type = automatic then you can use net start and net stop command on command line of windows to start and stop service respectively.

Answer (score 3):

you can find installUtil.exe at "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727", launch from CMD prompt, and add the path to your service

Comment: Example:
`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe /u "MyService.exe"
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe "MyService.exe"
net start "MyService"`

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get NSSM to work on my W7.  It always put its own path as the path to the program I put in the Path box.  Had to go manual with the sc example above.  That worked perfectly.  To get a list of sc parameters, just execute sc.  The two * preceeding the **ServiceName** will cause the ServiceName to appear at the top of the C:\Windows\System32\compmgmt.msc list.  To remove a service, use sc delete ServiceName.  You will have focus the list and use the Refresh menu item to see the change in compmgmt.msc.