# Find the service name for a service .exe file?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-server

I am wondering if its possible to determine the service name from the service .exe file?

The services are all written in C#.

Comment: It may actually be impossible, as the service name can be specified when the service is installed, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847771/how-to-install-a-service-on-windows-7-without-visual-studio

Comment: If the service is installed, you can enumerate all services, retrieve the configuration for each and compare the executable.  If the service is not installed, then no, there is no generic way to determine what the service name will be from the contents of the executable.